# How can I use an app after installing it via `brew pull`?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

Because of a reinstall of the OS and a not perfectly migration of my data I had to reinstall a few things. Under these things were homebrew and truecrypt.

`brew doctor` doesn't show any problems now. Only when I tried to install truecrypt. I know there is a version with `brew cask`. But I don't like the visual interface so I decided to search just with `brew search` for it. I show you what I did:

First I searched for truecrypt. Found it and installed it:

> `Newton:local hendrikwindel$ brew search truecrypt
>   No formula found for "truecrypt".
>   Searching pull requests...
>   Open pull requests:
>   truecrypt: Initial formula for version 7.1a (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/24078)`
>
> `Newton:local hendrikwindel$ brew pull https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/24078`
>   `#################################################################### 100,0%
>   ==> Applying patch Applying: 
>   truecrypt: Initial formula for version 7.1a`
>
> `/usr/local/.git/rebase-apply/patch:96: trailing whitespace.`
>
> `/usr/local/.git/rebase-apply/patch:97: space before tab in indent. 
>          FilePath Application::GetConfigFilePath (const wxString
>   &configFileName, bool createConfigDir)`
>
> `/usr/local/.git/rebase-apply/patch:98: space before tab in indent.   {`
>
> `/usr/local/.git/rebase-apply/patch:100: space before tab in indent.`
>
> `DirectoryPath configDir; /usr/local/.git/rebase-apply/patch:101:
>                 trailing whitespace. warning: squelched 144 whitespace errors warning: 148 lines applied after fixing whitespace errors.`
>
> `==> Patch closes issue #24078`
>
> `==> Patch changed:  Library/Formula/truecrypt.rb | 339 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  1 file changed, 339 insertions(+)`

After it was done I tried do use it:

> `Newton:local hendrikwindel$ man truecrypt
>     No manual entry for truecrypt`
>
> `Newton:local hendrikwindel$ truecrypt --mount /Users/***/física1
>   -bash: /Applications/TrueCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/Truecrypt: No such file or directory`

I think it didn't unistall the whole truecrypt.app or rather some lists are still there. If I remember correctly I had to add the terminal commands for truecrypt additionally when I installed truecrypt the first time - before I found out that homebrew exists.

So my question is: How can use truecrypt which I installed via `brew pull` and how can I fix this issue?

Edit:

> `Newton:local hendrikwindel$ type truecrypt
>   truecrypt is aliased to '/Applications/TrueCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/Truecrypt --text'`

Comment: What does `type truecrypt` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pull is, which means the repo is copied to your computer but you need to execute :

```
brew install truecrypt
```

to really install it.