# Truecrypt install fails - 3 out of 6 hunks FAILED

Tags: macos, install, homebrew, truecrypt

The first is just to show you where the installation is at this moment:

> `n102:~ hendrikwindel$ brew info truecrypt
>   truecrypt: stable 7.1a
>   http://truecrypt.org/
>   Conflicts with: fuse4x
>   Not installed
>   From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/truecrypt.rb
>   ==> Dependencies
>   Build: pkg-config ✔, nasm ✔
>   Required: wxmac ✔, osxfuse ✔`

And now occurs the issue:

> `n102:~ hendrikwindel$ brew install truecrypt
>   ==> Downloading ftp://ftp.archlinux.org/other/tc/truecrypt-7.1a.tar.gz
>   Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/truecrypt-7.1a.tar.gz
>   ==> Patching
>   patching file Main/Application.cpp
>   Hunk #1 succeeded at 36 with fuzz 2.
>   patching file Main/CommandLineInterface.cpp
>   patching file Main/Forms/Forms.cpp
>   Hunk #1 succeeded at 263 with fuzz 2.
>   Hunk #2 FAILED at 305.
>   Hunk #3 succeeded at 1443 with fuzz 2.
>   Hunk #4 FAILED at 1468.
>   Hunk #5 succeeded at 2894 with fuzz 2.
>   Hunk #6 FAILED at 2951.
>   3 out of 6 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file Main/Forms/Forms.cpp.rej
>   patching file Main/Forms/MainFrame.cpp
>   patching file Main/Forms/SelectDirectoryWizardPage.cpp
>   patching file Main/Forms/SelectDirectoryWizardPage.h
>   patching file Main/GraphicUserInterface.cpp
>   patching file Main/TextUserInterface.cpp
>   patching file Main/UserPreferences.cpp
>   patching file Platform/Unix/Process.cpp
>   Error: Applying DATA patch failed`

I have no idea what could be wrong. There is only a short [prehistory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126143/how-can-i-use-an-app-after-installing-it-via-brew-pull/126161#126161). But I think it isn't connected with this issue.

Comment: `brew info truecrypt =>
Error: No available formula for truecrypt`

Comment: That means what? I cannot follow you...

Comment: It means that I can't reproduce the error and it seems that truecrypt is not on brew... (but I might made a mistake). Try to run `brew update` then `brew info truecrypt`

Comment: Thats the [prehistory](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126143/how-can-i-use-an-app-after-installing-it-via-brew-pull/126161#126161)

Comment: Yes, I know, I'm the one who answer you. I told you to do that because `brew pull truecrypt` worked. It seems that truecrypt is no longueur on brew so I can't reproduce the error and that's might be the reason your installation is not working.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. However, because I had a few problems more I chose the good old windows-way: Reinstall the OS and everything. It worked :)

Comment: 19 days to re-install the OS :p anyway, can you tell us who did you install TrueCrypt this time ?

Answer (score 1):

### Bad News

The Truecrypt Formula on Homebrew has been removed due to bugs, and probably uncertainty in the community regarding truecrypt's safety.

There also used to be a homebrew cask which was [removed due to installation bugs](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/7693).  However, it was also moved to [homebrew-unofficial](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-unofficial/issues/42) and scheduled for removal.

For more information about the 3rd party audit, and why Truecrypt is still safe to use, please see [the links mentioned here](https://github.com/trinitronx/homebrew-truecrypt#is-truecrypt-still-safe-to-use).

### Good News

I have created a [Homebrew Tap for Truecrypt 7.1a](https://github.com/trinitronx/homebrew-truecrypt) which fixes the installation problem, and works on OS X `10.10` Yosemite!

## Installation

First, make sure you have installed [`homebrew-cask`](http://caskroom.io/) if you haven't yet:

```
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
```

Then, run the following in your command-line:

```
brew tap trinitronx/homebrew-truecrypt
```

## Usage

**Note**: For info run:

```
brew cask info truecrypt
```

Once the tap is installed, you can install `truecrypt`!

```
brew cask install truecrypt
```